# tableView reloadData/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths causes scroll flickering

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView with custom prototype cells with 50 rows. On `Load more` click, next 50 records should be loaded.

Now the first 50 records are scrolled smoothly, but on load more call, I call `reloadData` on tableView. Now the tableView scrolling is not smooth. I logged the indexes, I get the following log when I continously scroll upwards:

```
 index: 44
index: 43
index: 48
index: 49
index: 44
index: 43
index: 42
index: 47 // scrolls back causing flicker
index: 48
```

I also tried `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, still the same.

How do I solve this? Where am I getting wrong? I am using autolayout, is it causing the issue?

**edited code**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellProp" forIndexPath:indexPath];

//assign cell content

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: try `tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates()`

Comment: Have your registered any cell with 'cellProp' identifier for your tableview in viewDidLoad() ?

Comment: @Muneeba Nope, I haven't. I am using xib prototype cell and have given identifier there itself in xib.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:
```

Comment: Please provide additional details to indicate why this solves the issue so that future readers can benefit from this answer.  This answer has been flagged as "Low quality post" by StackOverflow

Comment: tried using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier forIndexPath`, still the same. Any idea why?

Comment: @z22 can you provide code for cell for row at index path

Comment: @AkleshRathaur pls check my edited post, added `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @z22 it looks like your table reloading multiple times at same time.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

And You should not tableview.ReloadData() when load more. Using:

```
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexpaths], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
```

Comment: tried using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier forIndexPath`, still the same. Actually I don't want to insert more rows, I just want to use the same rows with new data, like pagination.